# Set character encoding for file being uploaded by CURL

Tags: javascript, curl

I need to upload a CSV file using CURL command. The API where I am posting this file only accepts file in UTF-8 encoding. Here is my CURL command:

```
curl \
  --request POST \
  --url "url" \
  --header "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
  --form "file=file.csv;type=text/csv;charset=utf-8"
```

But when I run above command it fails to upload the file. Can someone please help?
Thanks.

Comment: What’s the actual encoding of the file? If it’s not UTF-8, then you need to convert it to an actual UTF-8 file first.

Comment: I have checked the encoding it is in UTF-8. But still doesn't work

Comment: Then that’s because you’re not actually uploading a file. `--form "file=file.csv"` does not make curl read any file data.